# Solr query a particular field ONLY using qf: parameter

Tags: indexing, solr, field

I'm trying to search for a particular set of keywords `keyword1`,`keyword2` or `keyword3` in a particular field. I'm doing it by using the query,

> http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted_shard2_replica2/browse?q=keyword1
>   keyword 2 keyword 3&qf=field1

However, when I run this it finds `keyword2` in another field `field2` and returns that row as well! As far as I understand, the `qf:field1` parameter limits the search for all the keywords in just `field1` right?

Where am I incorrect? Is it because of the schema that I have defined?

My schema config is:

```
<field name="field1" type="text_general" indexed="true"/>
<field name="field2" type="strings" indexed="false"/>
```

Comment: Had a look at your `solrconfig.xml`? Maybe your query handlers are configured with an override to the `qf` parameter.

Comment: change default parser. add `defType=dismax` to your URL

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [Solr Query Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/solr-query-debugger/gmpkeiamnmccifccnbfljffkcnacmmdl) Google Chrome plugin.

I suggest to use this debugger in order to see what's is execute and explain why your query have such strange behaviour.

Just execute the solr query in your browser and then start the Solr Query Debugger plugin.

In the plugin page you'll see `Debug` and `Echo` tabs where explain what's executed by Solr. In the `Explain` tab you'll see the score explanations  structured as a tree.

Comment: I'll give it a go! Unfortunately I'm on a VM which supports only firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using standard (default) Query parser or an eDisMax one? If standard (most likely), then you need to use **df** parameter.

**qf** parameter is used with [eDisMax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser), but then you need to also have defType=edismax

Enabling debug flag will show you against which fields the search is actually issued.